# Is IntelHD 4000 powerful enough to give me the best windows 8 experience?

Tags: windows-8, intel-graphics, user-experience

I have a Thinkpad with i5 3.0Ghz and 6GB of ram. The only thing I'm concerned is that i don't have any dedicated graphics card. Will my Intel HD 4000 suffice?

Comment: Yes. There is no Aero at all for example. Even a low-end card could provide _that_ experience with ease. :)

Comment: I'm running it on a GMA3100 (not even the X3100). I do believe this question is a little localised - you could easily check the system specs, and its only relevant to this graphics adaptor

Comment: @Shiki - can you provide some proof for that? as far as I know aero is cropped by win8, regardless of graphics card.

Comment: Run the [upgrade assistent](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8) and check what it tells you.

Comment: @Jook - That's what I meant. There is no Aero present at all, and a HD4000 would run Windows 7 with ease. (It does for me.) And Windows 8 worked for me with the same card too. Proof... I can't think any other proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that Microsoft itself is going to use it on the ["pro" version of it Surface](http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/en-GB/surface-with-windows-8-pro/specifications) tablet, I'd most definitely say that not only it will suffice, but it will be more than enough.

Of course if you'll need to use more graphic-intensive applications than windows 8 itself, a dedicated graphic card might be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 will be able to run on Intel HD 4000 all right, but you will not be able to run games properly.

Comment: Actually, many games run just fine with the HD4000. It is more powerful then it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I definetly would say YES.

Tested the HD4000 of my i5, was able to play Crysis 2 and Assasins Creed2 on medium settings.

Did not even bother the CPU-Boxed-Heatsink that much ~50.

look here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw8aDHIkDpc

this is not my test, but you will find many other like it ;) also HD-Movies and the overall Windows-Experience would have not much difference to a dedicated graphics card.

I would even suggest to spare a dedicated card, if you don't want to play excessivly high graphics.